# Radio Buttons ng-checked with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, radio-button, boolean, angular-ngmodel

In my HTML page, I have two sets of Boolean based radio buttons: Labeled: "Yes" and "No" / Values: *True* and *False* respectively. I'm populating a full form from a PostgreSQL database table to allow the authenticated user to view the form with populated data and edit the populated fields including the radio buttons, then save the form which will save the data to the DB. All of the other text fields populate without issue; it's both collection of radio buttons I am having an issue with pre-checkmarking the radio buttons.

The below does not pre-populate the checked on front end (but adds the correct attribute of *checked* in HTML source):

```
    <input id="billing-no" type="radio" name="billing" ng-model="person.billing" value="FALSE" ng-checked="person.billing == 'false'" />
    <input id="billing-yes" type="radio" name="billing" ng-model="person.billing" value="TRUE" ng-checked="person.billing == 'true'" />
```

However, this does check the correct radio button on load:

```
    <input id="billing-no" type="radio" name="billing" value="FALSE" ng-checked="person.billing == 'false'" />
    <input id="billing-yes" type="radio" name="billing" value="TRUE" ng-checked="person.billing == 'true'" />
```

**Note:** I needed to check against the string boolean value in the directive ng-checked since the boolean value always comes back as a string from PostgreSQL. This, apparently, was a part of PostgreSQL's design when querying data from columns that have boolean data types.

When adding the ng-model directive, the radio button no longer is checked (at least in the rendered browser view). The odd part is that I looked at the source and it clearly checks the correct one. What's even more odd, is that I have to click on the radio button *twice* to 'check' it. I've tested this in latest version of Chrome, FF, and IE and it all results in the same issue.

The question is: when adding the ng-model directive, why would the HTML source add 'checked' in the radio button attribute, but seemingly does not mark the radio button? Furthermore, why would I have to click twice on the radio button that IS supposed to be checked?

---

**Solution:**
To fix this, I removed the ng-checked directive from the radio buttons and only used ng-model as suggested by @Cypher and @aet. I then replaced the attribute *value* with the directive ng-value "true" & "false". After, I set the values in the controller.

**HTML**

```
<input id="billing-no" type="radio" name="billing" ng-model="person.billing" ng-value="false" />
<input id="billing-yes" type="radio" name="billing" ng-model="person.billing" ng-value="true" />
```

**Angular JS**

```
app.controller('peopleCtrl', function($scope, peopleFactory){
    ...
    peopleFactory.getPerson(personParams).then(function(data){
        $scope.person = data;
        /* moved from ng-checked */
        $scope.person.billing = data.billing == 'true';
    });
    ...
};
```

Comment: You really should not need to use ng-model and ng-checked at the same time. ng-checked is more like for a read-only checkbox thats reflecting some other value. If you just want it to start out checked set the model to true.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you should only use ng-model and should work well for you, here is the link to the official documentation of angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

The code from the example should not be difficult to adapt to your specific situation:

```
<script>
   function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.color = 'blue';
      $scope.specialValue = {
         "id": "12345",
         "value": "green"
      };
   }
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red">  Red <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" ng-value="specialValue"> Green <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
   <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: When switching back from different controller/scope to this raido button 's view, the pre-checked radio button is no longer checked even though data is still stored correctly. How to fix that?

Answer (score 7):

I solved my problem simply using `ng-init` for default selection instead of `ng-checked`

```
<div ng-init="person.billing=FALSE"></div>
<input id="billing-no" type="radio" name="billing" ng-model="person.billing" ng-value="FALSE" />
<input id="billing-yes" type="radio" name="billing" ng-model="person.billing" ng-value="TRUE" />
```

Answer (score 3):

[Personal Option]
Avoiding using $scope, based on John Papa [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

so my idea is take advantage of the current model:

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
   var app = angular.module('way', [])
   app.controller('Decision', Decision);

   Decision.$inject = [];     

   function Decision(){
     var vm = this;
     vm.checkItOut = _register;

     function _register(newOption){
       console.log('should I stay or should I go');
       console.log(newOption);  
     }
   }

     
     
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="way">
  <div ng-controller="Decision as vm">
    <form name="myCheckboxTest" ng-submit="vm.checkItOut(decision)">
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="option" ng-model="decision.myWay"
                           ng-value="false" ng-checked="!decision.myWay"> Should I stay?
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="option" ng-value="true"
                           ng-model="decision.myWay" > Should I go?
                </label>
  
</form>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I hope I could help ;)

Comment: Technically, speaking one should use `vm.myWay` :)

Answer (score 1):

Please explain why same `ng-model` is used? And what value is passed through `ng- model` and how it is passed? To be more specific, if I use `console.log(color)` what would be the output?

Comment: You should include what you have tried as code as well as any errors you get back. Otherwise this is a question more suited to Google, not a QA site.