# update radio value in angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, controller

I have a list of radio button values in ControllerA, printed in the view with ng-repeat. The list comes from a service. Now I want to check which radio button is selected in ControllerB.

How do I get the current selected value?

Do I need to add a $watch function in ControllerA and update the service that way?

Or is there a different way of basically binding a variable from a controller to variable in a service?

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: Use ng-model answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279296/radio-buttons-ng-checked-with-ng-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to set a `$watch`; it's all about sharing state between controllers.

## Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('myState', function() {

  // For this example I'm just returning the state directly, but it can also
  // be returned from some function or even some backend api. Just remember
  // that factories (services/providers) are singletons and will point always
  // to the same instance within your app.

  return {
    chickenEgg: 'egg'
  };

});

app.controller('ControllerA', function($scope, myState) {
  $scope.formData = myState;
});

app.controller('ControllerB', function($scope, myState) {
  $scope.result = myState;
});
```

## Html

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerA">

    <h2>ControllerA</h2>

    <form class="form">
      <label>Chicken or the Egg?</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="chicken" ng-model="formData.chickenEgg">Chicken
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="egg" ng-model="formData.chickenEgg">Egg
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>

  <div ng-controller="ControllerB">

    <h2>ControllerB</h2>
    <pre><code>result = {{ result | json }}</code></pre>

  </div>
```

You can see it in action in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/biy7g88QEPgHiSqO9s9K?p=preview) plunker.

Comment: Ah, I see. The service is in effect bound via ng-model. Nifty, didn't expect that behavior from just `$scope.formData = myState` and `ng-model="formData.chickenEgg"`