# Angularjs radio selection as checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am trying to create selection when new user is created it will need a group. It is working nicely, but the "checked" option doesn't work for some reason. How can I make the "user" as checked so it would be true if create new user button is pressed?

```
 <div class="radio-group" required>
      <h3>Set user group</h3>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="groupradio" value="2" ng-model="groups.group" required> Admin
    </label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="groupradio" value="1" ng-model="groups.group" checked> User
    </label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="groupradio" value="3" ng-model="groups.group"> Viewer
    </label>
    </div>
  <button class="btn-sonera" ng-click="createUser(user, groups)"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create user</button>
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279296/radio-buttons-ng-checked-with-ng-model

Comment: We are probably missing some context. As you can see on this plunker ( https://plnkr.co/edit/VE93DmUXIBxRYJX7mpgy?p=preview ) with your code the user checkbox is checked.

Comment: checked="checked" doesnt work either. I wonder how the plunker works and not my code. I had it working sometime then it just disappeared...

Answer (score 1):

With AngularJs best is use its directive:

```
ng-checked="variable"
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it checked with `ng-init="groups.group=1"` Because I need the value assigned to the radio. Is there something wrong using it this way?

Full code

```
<div class="radio-group" required>
  <h3>Set user group</h3>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="groupradio" value="2" ng-model="groups.group" required> Admin
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="groupradio" value="1" ng-model="groups.group" ng-init="groups.group=1"> User
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="groupradio" value="3" ng-model="groups.group"> Viewer
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try by using ng-value

```
 <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="groups.group" value="1">
    Admin
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="groups.group" value="2">
    User
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="groups.group" value="3">
    Viewer
  </label><br/>
```

in controller

```
 $scope.createUser = function(user, groups){
        groups.group = "2";

      };
```

Comment: No luck with the ng-value.

Comment: I think it actually works also like this: $scope.groups = {group: 1};

Comment: I solved problem using ng-init, but this could be second answer. So yes.

Comment: @Shnigi Ok.. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/4VtblBSWROLTETW5Ie5C?p=preview

The core code:

```
  $scope.groups = {
    admin : false, 
    user: false, 
    viewer: false
  };
```

And in the view:

```
<button class="btn-sonera" ng-click="groups.user=true"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create user</button>
```

Note how each ng-model is bound to an object, ie:  groups.admin, groups.user etc.