# AngularJS radio button selected value not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in Angularjs and web html. I have two radio buttons for male and female. I want to set male as checked by default. I tried many ways but it is not working. Finally i tried with ng-checked="True" and it worked. But when i check male i am getting undefined in angular code.

```
<label for="male" class="male">
                                {{ 'Male' | translate }}
                                <span class="input-icon"><img src="images/male-icon.png"></span>
                                <input type="radio" id="male" name="selector" ng-model="Gender" value="M" ng-checked="true">
                                <span class="selector-male"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label for="female" class="female">
                                {{ 'Female' | translate }}
                                <span class="input-icon"><img src="images/female-icon.png"></span>
                                <input type="radio" id="female" name="selector" ng-model="Gender" value="F">
                                <span class="selector-female"></span>
                            </label>
```

Above code selects male by default. But problem is when i select female i am getting female in below code.

```
  Gender: $scope.Gender
```

Whenever i dont select anything(By default male will be clicked) i am getting undefined in    Gender: $scope.Gender. May i know the reason why i am getting undefined? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio Buttons ng-checked with ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279296/radio-buttons-ng-checked-with-ng-model)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

`ng-checked=true` will set the checkbox only as true and not the currentValue in question. To fix, you should:

`ng-checked="Gender"` in HTML and `$scope.Gender = 'M'` in your controller.

If you don't want to add anothing in controller, wrap the code in a div as:

`<div ng-init="Gender='M'"><label></label></div>`

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/i4WK990a8zHyYkoW8pIb?p=preview

Comment: Additionally, I think you need to use `ng-value` rather than just `value`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: in this case, value will suffice. ng-value when you have to interpolate dynamic values.

Comment: Thank you. No luck.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/PLVX9U9l01xoXCRmuDxt?p=preview this work, can you match the code from here? i have used the `ng-init` approach

Answer (score 0):

remove name attribute and ng-checked then it works fine.